# I cannot use Websocket package on NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, nestjs

I'm trying to work with websockets on Nestjs, i install the dependencies

`yarn add @nestjs/websockets @nestjs/platform-socket.io`

I generated a example resource for the websockets

`nest g res messagesWs --no-spec`

Then this message shows up in my terminal

> TypeError: this.metadataScanner.getAllMethodNames is not a function

[This is a capture from the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEE50.png)

What can i do?
PD: sorry for my bad english

I search for that function getAllMethodNames but i didn't get anything

Comment: Could you share the messageWs file and the module you added it to, please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved it by downgrading a few versions.

From

`"@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "9.3.6", "@nestjs/websockets": "9.3.6"`

to

`"@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "9.1.6", "@nestjs/websockets": "9.1.6"`

Answer (score 17):

`@nestjs/core` and `@nestjs/websockets` versions should always be **in sync**.  For example, if the latest version of your locally installed `@nestjs/websockets` package is 9.3.6, then you have to make sure that `@nestjs/core` is also on 9.3.6.

Once you fix this up, the error will go away.

Comment: I assume there's no way to express such a constraint in the package file? So you have to resort to specifying exact versions in the package.json file?

Answer (score 1):

I back to v.

```
"@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^7.6.15",
"@nestjs/websockets": "^7.6.15",
```

is working

Comment: Thanks, i tried with 9.1.6 version and its working

Answer (score 1):

It wokrs for me follow these steps:

1. remove `node_modules` folder
2. from `package.json` remove `^` before the version number
3. npm install

Answer (score 0):

Work for me:

Get `@nestjs/core` version in `pnpm-lock.yaml`

Then install `@nestjs/platform-socket.io` and `@nestjs/websockets` as **same version** of `@nestjs/core`

Or upgrade all packages about nestjs to latest, `pnpm up`